# What print management tools are available for a large organization?

Tags: printing, network-printer, print-server, shared-printers

Our organization uses the [Pharos](http://www.pharos.com/) print management software to allow users to manage jobs to different output devices, as well as tracking usage for the users and allowing / denying access to different print resources.

The contract is coming up for renewal and I'm looking for other alternatives so that we at least know what is out there and what the competitor's pricing is like when it's time to negotiate.

A search for Print Management Software also turned up:

http://www.papercut.com/

http://ww.czsolution.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Papercut is actually a really good alternative. The price is decent and only gets better as you scale.

Edit: and I wouldn't trust CZsolutions if they can't keep their site online :P